# Replicating GSAP ScrollTrigger effect with vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, gsap

So, say there is a recurring function with `requestAnimationFrame` to move an image from `left: 0` all the way to `left:100%` where its change in value is dependent on the `scrollY` value received through a `'scroll'` `eventListener`..
The parent of this image is a `div` with `min-height: 100vh`.

I want to replicate the **GSAP's scrollTrigger** function with **vanilla JS** which would keep extending the parent's `height` over `100vh` until the image's `left` value has reached `100%`. After that the parent `div` will no longer expand its height and will also scroll up with the image.
Basically, I am just looking for a way to make this **scrollTrigger** function happen with **vanilla JS**. Would this be the ideal approach for it?

`position: sticky` is not the solution here as I want to make the user feel that the rest of the DOM elements below are '*held*' down and can't be scrolled in view till the image 's `left` value turns to `100%`.

In other words, how to make the parent `div`'s height high enough that the entire animation on the `child` is completed till you reach the `div`'s bottom by scrolling?

I hope I made sense.

```
<div class="parent">
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

A working demo of what I need is the effect on this CodePen. You can see that the text **Cool, right?** is not scrolled into view till the entire shoe is created:
[CodePen link](https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/gOabMXv)